# How to disable the auto-complete feature on periods

Tags: vim, neocomplcache, spf13vim

If someone presses the period key while writing code the auto-complete feature tries to give suggestions for what could follow after that period. This mechanism may be too slow to be useful sometimes.

How to disable this behavior? Triggering this feature by hitting a hot-key should still be possible.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin responsible for that behavior comes with an exhaustive documentation that you can access from Vim with `:help neocomplcache`. The answer to your question is *very* easy to find.

Also, drop SPF-13 as soon as possible: the short term benefits are not worth the medium/long term losses.

Comment: Can you post the snippet from the help to disable it? This is at best a link-only answer.

Comment: Why is spf13 not worth for long term use and what is the command to solve the question? I've tried `g:neocomplcache_disable_auto_complete=1` which actually disables the popup but still triggers the problem with the delay

Comment: You are looking for a command, there's a "commands" section, the command you are looking for is there. Distributions like SPF-13 prevent you from learning Vim and favorize lazyness.